# How To Add Multiple Other Controls To Single Controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm From Vietnames , I Ask Question :

How To Add More Objects On Parent Object, I'm Trying To Place Child Object Properties On Parent Object's Area To Make It Transparent.

I Tried Following Method

```
PictureBox.Add(PictureBox2);
PictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

But This Reduces Performance Leads to Lag Form Interface Upon Startup.

I Have A Lot Of Objects I Need To Put On The Parent Class , I Also Tried Through Thread , BackgroundWorker , But All To No avail.

I WANT TO ADD MULTIPLE OBJECTS ONLY 1 LINE , instead of having to WRITE MANY LINES AS BELOW : (HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(Controls 1 ,Controls 2 , Controls 3 , Controls 4 . vv) .

1 The Best Possible Method To Solve The Problem I Have.

```
    private void Controls_2()
    {
        Thread HB_2 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(TITLE_ID3)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(bunifuLabel12)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(API_ONLINE_ID_3)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(bunifuLabel36)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(PLAYER_ID3)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(bunifuLabel34)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(pictureBox4)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(bunifuLabel2)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(FLAG_ID_3)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(bunifuLabel22)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(STAR_1_ID3)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(STAR_2_ID3)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(STAR_3_ID3)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(STAR_4_ID3)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(STAR_5_ID3)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(SELECT_ID3)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(SELECT_ID4)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(RIGHT_Gif_HANG_2)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(LEFT_Gif_HANG_2)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(TITLE_ID4)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(bunifuLabel17)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(API_ONLINE_ID_4)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(bunifuLabel49)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(PLAYER_ID4)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(bunifuLabel51)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(pictureBox9)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(bunifuLabel7)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(FLAG_ID_4)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(bunifuLabel27)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(STAR_1_ID4)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(STAR_2_ID4)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(STAR_3_ID4)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(STAR_4_ID4)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(STAR_5_ID4)));
            HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(Patch_HANG_2)));
        });
        HB_2.IsBackground = true;
        HB_2.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Hello Bình, welcome to stack overflow! To get the best possible answer, please take a few minutes to read the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Basically the more clear and easy to understand your question is, the better the answers you will receive. Are you using VB or C#? Is your application Win Forms or WPF? **What are you trying to achieve exactly?** Show us your code!

Comment: Hello , I'm Using C# .NET 7 WinForm : Code : HEARTBEAT_2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(TITLE_ID3)));

Comment: The shown code does not do anything helpful. ALL UI operations have to be done in the main thread to what this code actually adheres. But you create a background thread to then invoke back into the main thread to just add controls. Nothing is done in the background thread itself and adding controls to something visual isn't a complex task. It at least does not change anything concerning how the added control works or is painted itself. So just remove all of that and just simply add the controls.

Comment: do you have any example? , I would like to see the example you gave , thanks

Comment: Just call `HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.Add(TITLE_ID3);` without the extra thread? If that happens multiple times at runtime while the form is shown surround that code with a pair of SuspendLayout/ResumeLayout calls. That might prevent triggering multiple repaints. If you want a single call you might want to create an extension method with a `params control[] mycontrols` parameter and then loop over myControls and add all of them. You would get your proposed syntax then. But surely without changing anything regarding performance.

Comment: Looking at the source AddRange seems helpful `HEARTBEAT_2.Controls.AddRange(new Control[]{ bunifuLabel12, API_ONLINE_ID_3, etc.});` It already does suspending layouting until all controls are added.

Comment: @BìnhNguyễn Please, instead of answering in comments, update your question. Please correct your spelling: we but low case everywhere but at the beginning of a sentence and for proper names (eg., David, Alice, Paris, Madrid etc). You want to inline code with back ticks eg., `myfunction()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what Ralf is suggesting:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control[] ctrls = {
        TITLE_ID3, bunifuLabel12,API_ONLINE_ID_3, bunifuLabel36, PLAYER_ID3,
        bunifuLabel34,pictureBox4,bunifuLabel2,FLAG_ID_3,bunifuLabel22,
        STAR_1_ID3, STAR_2_ID3,STAR_3_ID3,STAR_4_ID3,STAR_5_ID3,
        SELECT_ID3,SELECT_ID4,RIGHT_Gif_HANG_2,LEFT_Gif_HANG_2,TITLE_ID4,
        bunifuLabel17,API_ONLINE_ID_4,bunifuLabel49,PLAYER_ID4,bunifuLabel51,
        pictureBox9,bunifuLabel7,FLAG_ID_4,bunifuLabel27,STAR_1_ID4,
        STAR_2_ID4,STAR_3_ID4,STAR_4_ID4,STAR_5_ID4,Patch_HANG_2
    };
    this.Controls.AddRange(ctrls);
    foreach(Control ctrl in ctrls)
    {
        ctrl.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
}
```